# Why does this "common" idiom for thread-safe event-calling in C# works at all?

Tags: c#

I'm reading *Effective C#* and I came across the following pattern to improve event-calling behavior and make it thread-safe:

```
    public class EventSource {
        private EventHandler<int> Updated;
        private int counter; 

        public void RaiseUpdates(){
          counter++;
          var handler = Updated;
          if (handler != null){
              handler(this, counter);
        }
```

The book claims that since there a "shallow copy" in the assignment to `handler`, the call `handler(this, counter)` will call all registered clients even if moments before one of them unsubscribed. **But aren't delegates in C# reference types? Wouldn't this assignment just create a new reference for the underlying delegate object?**

Comment: This is because `if (Updated != null) Updated(this, counter)` has a race condition.  In that case Updated could be set to null after the null check but before it's invoked.

Comment: Emphasis: the book is out of date; you should just use `counter++; Updated?.Invoke(this, counter);` - same logic, just: less stuff to remember to do

Comment: To zer0, that part I did get.

Comment: @MarcGravell Why does the null-conditional solution work? Does the C# specification guarantee atomicity? Does it make an underlying copy of the delegate?

Comment: @estefano yes, it copies the operand (the reference in this case; not a copy of the delegate itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate object is immutable, so a copy of the reference to it is fine. A standalone local copy of a reference to an immutable object is pretty much the gold standard for avoiding a thread-race problem.

When you add/remove an event subscription, `Delegate.Combine` et al create a **new** delegate instance every time it changes (or `null` if you unsubscribe the last handler) and assigns a reference (/ `null`) to that new object to the backing field. That is why the snapshot is helpful.

BTW : in modern C#, you can just use `TheEvent?.Invoke(....)`, which does this for you.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank oh so very much kind sir. 

Comment: Reference: ECMA-334 C# Language Specification, ch. 20.5: `Once instantiated, a delegate instance always refers to the same invocation list. [Note: Remember, when
two delegates are combined, or one is removed from another, a new delegate results with its own invocation list; the invocation lists of the delegates combined or removed remain unchanged. end note]`

Comment: Yes, the book does endorse this new solution, but why does.it work? Does the null-conditional operator make a copy of its operand?

Comment: @estefano-ppt yes, it does