# Why does the null-conditional operator promote thread-safety in C#?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, null-conditional-operator

There's a modern idiom in C# that utilizes the null-conditional operator to promote thread-safety when using delegates. Namely:

```
Update?.Invoke(this, theArgs);
```

Why does this work? Does the C# specification guarantee atomicity in the operation? Does the null-conditional operator make an underlying copy of its operand before executing the Invoke() method?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678553/why-does-this-common-idiom-for-thread-safe-event-calling-in-c-sharp-works-at-a from a few minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

the Null-conditional operater is roughly equivalent to:

```
var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(…);
}
```

The part where it creates a local variable? That is what would help with thread safety.

However is is not 100% reliable. See, people have used this pattern before. It has been standing advise for events. But unless you mark `handler` as `volatile`, compiler or JiT compiler might cut it out due to being a underused variable. The compiler setting it in itself, might prevent that optimsiation.

But at the end of the day, the only reliable thing is a lock statement.

Comment: For delegates, it does indeed guarantee [thread-safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#thread-safe-delegate-invocation).

Comment: @Zer0 As I wrote, this pattern has been the go to for decades. But the Compiler Optimisaiton were prone to cut out that local variable. And I am not certain they are reigned in for this case. Without volatile mark, it might be optimized away down the line.

Comment: You bring up a good point about `volatile`, but the documentation does state this works.  _How_ it works I think is a valid question.  C# spec, the compiler, etc..

Comment: @Zer0: as that will not let me rest, I had to ask it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679273/is-the-null-conditional-operators-thread-safety-save-from-compiler-optimisations

Comment: Yeah I wasn't 100% sure myself so I dug around until I fully understood, then [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786442/3980331) while looking and it goes into great detail about how there still exists a race condition here I normally don't think about.  Great read.